# how to add cornered borders for bar chart ng2-charts

Tags: angular, bar-chart, ng2-charts

I cant find a way to add border radius for bars in the chart, the solutions I found online are related to chartjs but im not sure how to do this using ng2-charts

```
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        curvature: 1,
        // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
        scales: { xAxes: [{
            display:false,
            barThickness: 22,
            stacked: true
            }], yAxes: [{
            display:false,
            barThickness: 22,
            stacked: true
            }] },
    };
 public barChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
    public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
    public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
        { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40] },
        { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90] }
    ];
    barChartColors: Color[] = [
        { backgroundColor: '#34bfa3' },
        { backgroundColor: '#f4f5f8' },
    ];


<canvas baseChart  height="100"
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [colors]="barChartColors"
            [chartType]="barChartType">
    </canvas>
```

I need to know if this is achievable with ng2-charts and how?

Comment: any suggestion ?